# How do I make a class correctly?

Tags: c++

My class is not being defined correctly. What do I need to change to make it work?  My `ExpTree` will not work at all, when I go to the implementation file it will not compile, and will give me an error for my class, constructor and destructor. It says that `ExpTree` is an anonymous struct.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#ifndef ExpTree
#define ExpTree
using namespace std;

class ExpTree{
 public:

  ExpTree() {root = NULL;}
  ~ExpTree();

  void build (istream& in_s);

  void prefix (ostream& out_s);
  void infix(ostream& out_s);
  void postfix(ostream& out_s);
  int value();

 private:

  struct Node
  {
    int operand;
    char optr;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
  };
  Node *root;

  void destroy(Node* root);
  Node* help_build (istream& in_s);
  void print_prefix(ostream& out_s, Node* r);
  void print_infix(ostream& out_s, Node *r);
  void print_postfix(ostream& out_s, Node *r);
  int find_value(Node *r);

};

#endif
```

Comment: Why do you have a `#define ExtTree` statement above the `ExtTree` class? That is interfering with the compiler's ability to process the `ExtTree` class correctly, so you need to get rid of it, or at least rename it. I suspect this code is inside of a header file, and you are trying to `#define` a header guard for it, is that correct? If so, you need to use a unique name for the guard, such as `ExtTree_H` (and all of your `#include` statements should be moved inside of the guard).

Comment: Okay thank you for that information. I think I understand what I was doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the same name for your `#define` include guard and anything else.

`#define ExpTree` tells the "preprocessor" to "learn that `ExpTree` means an empty piece of source code". This does have the desired effect that if the header gets included additional times, the contents will be skipped since the `#ifndef` will notice that the preprocessor already knows a meaning of `ExpTree`.

But, with the `ExtTree` name being used this way, it has the undesired effect that every time `ExpTree` appears later in your code, it gets replaced with empty code! So the "compiler" sees code like this:

```
class {
  public:
    () {root = NULL;}
    ~ ();
// ...
```

Which yes, will produce tons of errors.

There are a number of common patterns for include guards, like `#define PROJECTNAME_EXPTREE_H`. You want to try to reduce the chance it will ever be the same as a name some other code uses.

P.S. It's common practice to put `#include` directives inside the `#ifndef ... #endif` guard too. If your header was already seen, those headers were already included and don't need to be re-scanned again.

Comment: Would it be bad if I just did not put in the #define? I got my program to work when I didn't use the #define. Or should I name it something else.

Comment: It depends on why you created the `#define` in the first place.  If you expect your file will only ever be included one time per translation unit, then it is safe to omit the `#define`.  But if there is any chance that your file could be included multiple times, then leave the `#define` in, just give it a unique name. It doesn't hurt to have it.